# How to access object value in same object

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create environment object as follows:

```
export const environment = 
    {
        production: false,
        hmr       : false,
        api: {
            auth: {
                protocol: 'http',
                host: 'localhost',
                port: '8083',
                api_path: 'api',
                version: {
                    path: 'v',
                    major: 1,
                    minor: 0,
                    patch: 0,
                },
                url: this.api.auth.protocol + '://' + this.api.auth.host + ':' + this.api.auth.port,
                controllers: {
                    auth: {
                        service_name: 'auth',
                        base_url: this.api.auth.url + '/' + this.api.auth.controllers.auth.service_name + '/'
                            + this.api.auth.api_path + '/' + this.api.auth.version.path + '/'
                            + this.api.auth.version.major + '.' + this.api.auth.version.minor + '.' + this.api.auth.version.patch + '/',
                        refresh_token_url: this.api.auth.controllers.auth.base_url + '/refresh_token',
                        login_url: this.api.auth.controllers.auth.base_url + '/login',
                        logout_url: this.api.auth.controllers.auth.base_url + '/logout'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I want to access previously assigned value in the same object. Like I want to access "api.auth.protocol" in "api.auth.url" as "this.api.auth.protocol" so that I can make http://localhost:8083 from  api.auth.host and api.auth.protocol. But I can't access in "api.auth.protocol" in "api.auth.url". After compiling error shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined". How can I access previous object value from same object?

I am new in this field. Sorry if I asked silly question.

Comment: I think you should something like appsettings.json, not this way.Example, https://www.codemag.com/article/1801021/Configuration-Settings-for-Angular-Applications

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot do that in initializer.
Pull out `protocol` to external variable.

```
export const protocol = "http";
```

and then use the variable/const in both or more places in the initializer.